# SQL Server 2005. Convert(nvarchar, my_datetime_column, 126). Missing milliseconds

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Server 2005 and a table with 2 columns of type `datetime`.

My query is:

```
select 
    DocDate, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar, DocDate, 126), 
    _stamp, 
    CONVERT(nvarchar, _stamp, 126) 
from 
    dochead 
where 
    id = 4493130
```

Result is:

```
DocDate                   (no column name)      _stamp                    (no column name)
2011-08-31 00:00:00.000   2011-08-31T00:00:00   2011-08-31 16:01:17.243   2011-08-31T16:01:17.243
```

As you can see second column has not milliseconds. Why?

Comment: You should always define a **length** for your `(n)varchar` column! Otherwise, you might end up with a 1-character long string at some point.... so use `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ...)` or something like that - just a good habit to adopt

Comment: Why do you think it important that the milliseconds be included when they are 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no milliseconds part at all, you can add `.000` manually:

```
select 
    DocDate, 
    left(CONVERT(nvarchar, DocDate, 126) + '.000', 23)
    _stamp, 
    left(CONVERT(nvarchar, _stamp, 126) + '.000', 23)
from 
    dochead 
where 
    id = 4493130
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/955

Answer (score 2):

It's a valid ISO 8601 datetime representation, which is all that [format `126`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says that you get. Hate to quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but:

> - For reduced accuracy,[5] any number of values may be dropped from any of the date and time representations, but in the order from the least to the most significant. For example, "2004-05" is a valid ISO 8601 date, which indicates May (the fifth month) 2004. This format will never represent the 5th day of an unspecified month in 2004, nor will it represent a time-span extending from 2004 into 2005.
> - If necessary for a particular application, the standard supports the addition of a decimal fraction to the smallest time value in the representation.

So the decimal fraction of a second (e.g. milliseconds) are an optional part of this format.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I've got. I've thought (accordig to sql books) that part (milliseconds) is mandatory. In a part of our system this date is parsed as ParseExact. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
DocDate, 
CONVERT(nvarchar, DocDate, 126), _stamp, 
CONVERT(nvarchar, _stamp, 126) 
from  dochead where 
id = 4493130
```